# Show that the only continuous solution of $g(s+t) = g(s)g(t)$ with $s,t \ge 0$ is $g(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If for any $s,t \ge 0$:

\begin{align*}
  g(s+t) &= g(s) g(t) \\
\end{align*}

Show that the only right-continuous solution of this is:

\begin{align*}
  g(x) &= e^{-\lambda x} \\
\end{align*}

My textbook claims this. Clearly the solution is continuous and satisfies the given condition. I'd like to see a basic sketch of a proof and I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: $0$ is also a solution

Comment: Why e? Can be any positive real number

Comment: What does this have to do with probability?.

Comment: This functional equation comes up when the memoryless property of the exponential distribution is discussed. Maybe that's why probability-distributions are mentioned.

Comment: I see, however this question regards Cauchy Functional equations and I believe it is a duplicate question (I've seen similar questions from different posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is an integer then
$$
g(ns)=g(s)^n.
$$
Let $c=g(1).$ Then if $a/b$ is any rational number,
$$
g(a/b)^b=g(a)=g(1)^a=c^a
$$
so $c\geq 0$ and $g(a/b)=c^{a/b}.$
Then you can use right-continuity to show that $g(x)=c^x$ holds for all other real numbers. Then if $c>0$, define $\lambda=-\ln c$.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment constant $0$ is a solution. Suppose $g$ is non-zero. Then, one can show that $g$ is positive everywhere. Once you take the $\log $ of both sides, you obtain the Cauchy functional equation. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).